# error in InvokeMember SetProperty with casting

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pinvoke

I want to set property via .InvokeMember but I can not do this when casting is required,

```
public Class A{
  private B? _bb;
  public B? Bb{
    get{return _bb;}
    set {_bb=value;}
  }
}


public struct B {
  public B(int i){}
  public static implicit operator B(int p)
        {   B q = new B(p);
            return q;
        }
}
```

when I set it via Simple Code,it works.

```
A myA=new A();
myA.Bb=12;
```

but when I try to set it via InvokeMember,it does not work with casting,it just work for direct type.

this code works

```
A myA=new A();
myA.GetType().InvokeMember("Bb", 
   BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,myA, new object[] { new B(12) });
```

but the next line , gives error and says that it can not find property "Bb"

```
A myA=new A();
myA.GetType().InvokeMember("Bb", 
   BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,myA, new object[] { 12});
```

I have to use it by the last way,how should I have to do it ?

Comment: Is this really the code you're testing with? I ask because you made the field/property nullable, and B is a class, you can't have `Nullable<T>` when `T` is a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't even compile. B is a reference type, thus you cannot use it as a generic argument for the `Nullable<T>` class:

```
// Impossible
private B? _bb;
```

This being said, assuming you fix your code and declare B as a value type (using a `struct` for example), the problem is that Reflection doesn't use implicit conversion operators.

You may take a look at the [following thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/59c82a52-e6a2-4b0a-ba00-b9e655de947d/) for one possible solution.

Another possibility is to invoke the `op_Implicit` static method emitted by the compiler to convert the integer into an instance of `B`:

```
A myA = new A();
var op_Implicit = typeof(B).GetMethod("op_Implicit");
B myB = (B)op_Implicit.Invoke(null, new object[] { 12 });
myA.GetType().InvokeMember("Bb", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, myA, new object[] { myB });
```